# Family bounded in $\mathcal{L}^1$ has limit a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{F} , \mu )$ be a measure space.

Suppose $\lbrace X_n \rbrace$ is a family of functions in $\mathcal{L}^1$, bounded in $\mathcal{L}^1$ i.e. there exist $K \geq 0 $ such that $$||X_n||_1 \leq K  \ \ \forall n $$Is it true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$$ exists a.e. ? Why ?

Comment: The answer is no. (Keyword: Oscillation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take in $\mathcal L^1[0,1]$:
$$
X_{2n}(x)=1\quad\text{nad}\quad X_{2n-1}(x)=0.
$$
Worse example, in $\mathcal L^1[0,1]$, 
where not even a subsequence converges pointwise is
$$
X_n(x)=\sin nx, \quad n\in\mathbb N.
$$

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider this sequence.  Let $f_1$ be the indicator function on $[0,1/2]$, then $f_2$ be the indicator function on $[1/2,1]$. Now go back to zero and go by quarters to get $f_3$ through $f_6$. Continue in this fashion with 1/8, 1/16, etc.

This sequence will converge to 0 in $\mathcal{L}^1$ but it will diverge by a.e. pointwise. This will occur at any number that is not a dyadic rational.